# Why i can't import BaseModel from Pydantic?

Tags: python, class, import, pydantic

enter code hereI try to import pydantic (1.8.1 ver.) library.

When i try import BaseModel from pydantic I get error.
I try to import like this
`from pydantic import BaseModel`

Output:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseModel' from partially initialized module 'pydantic' (most likely due to a circular import) (D:\temp\main.py)

This is my code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel  
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from typing import List, Dict

class CurrencyRequest(BaseModel):

    base: str = "EUR"
    symbols: List[str]
    start_at: date = None
    end_at: date = None

    def __str__(self):
        return """
        Dates range: {start} - {end}
        Base currency: {base}
        Different currencies: {curr}
        """.format(
            start=self.start_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if self.start_at is not None else "...",
            end=self.end_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if self.end_at is not None else "...",
            base=self.base,
            curr=self.symbols
        )
```

[This is link to photo with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XShm0.png)

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Could you show how do you execute the above code? Is this file is main.py? if not please include it.

Comment: @Rafał I execute this through command prompt. The name of file is exchange_rates_api.py

Comment: Thank you, Could you list all files from C:\Users\CJ\Desktop\projects\python\pydatic directory?

Comment: it looks like the issue is circular dependency I would go from the main file you are running to its imports and check where your imports are creating some sort of circle :)

Comment: @Rafał So i have file with code and python virtual environment (venv) with pydantic lib, that's all

Comment: @OmerShacham thanks i try it :) If it's work i will post solution  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have a package or a module with name "pydantic" in the root path.

EDIT: on the screenshot of the error you have "pydantic" folder. Try to rename it