# cannot import name 'BaseModel' from 'pydantic' (unknown location)

Tags: python, import, dataprep

I was trying to import the library dataprep, and it looks like it has some problems.

The code was like this:

```
from dataprep.eda import plot
# plot_correlation,create_report,plot_missing
```

here is the error：

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[146], line 1
----> 1 from dataprep.eda import plot

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataprep\eda\__init__.py:8
      5 from bokeh.io import output_notebook
      7 from ..utils import is_notebook
----> 8 from .correlation import compute_correlation, plot_correlation, render_correlation
      9 from .create_report import create_report
     10 from .create_db_report import create_db_report

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataprep\eda\correlation\__init__.py:10
      7 import dask.dataframe as dd
      8 import pandas as pd
---> 10 from ..configs import Config
     11 from ..container import Container
     12 from ...progress_bar import ProgressBar

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataprep\eda\configs.py:23
     20 from __future__ import annotations
     22 from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional, Tuple, Union
---> 23 from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
     24 from ..utils import is_notebook
     27 # This dictionary map the plot names in display to their canonicalized names in Config

ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseModel' from 'pydantic' (unknown location)
```

How do I resolve the error and successfully import the `dataprep` library?

Comment: What version of `pydantic` and `dataprep` do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How do I resolve the error and successfully import the dataprep library?*

Without knowing your versions of `pydantic` and `dataprep`, you should consider the following:

1. check your path. See similar discussion in this SO: [Why i can't import BaseModel from Pydantic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645515/why-i-cant-import-basemodel-from-pydantic)
2. update your version of `dataprep`, which should update `pydantic` as well (#dependencies). If `pydantic` is not updated, kindly update it manually with `pip install -U pydantic` or `conda`.
3. raise an issue on [`dataprep github`](https://github.com/sfu-db/dataprep/issues)
4. [not recommended] '*manually*' edit the `__init__.py` in `pydantic`: check your `~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydantic` folder.

---

I had a similar error message earlier this week but from `pygwalker`.  See this SO: [PyGWalker: cannot import name 'Field' from 'pydantic'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76905259/pygwalker-cannot-import-name-field-from-pydantic)